# How does the COMSPEC environmental variable effect a cgi executable?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cgi

It appears that a cgi app (in C, VS C++) does not inherit the COMSPEC environmental variable.

When adding the variable to the application:
`_putenv( "COMSPEC=C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe" );` [// C4996](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28VS.80%29.aspx)

the cgi application no longer executes from the browser but is interpreted as a file for download. (i.e. - Save this file?)

My question is why does adding this variable to the cgi app change the way it excutes (or no longer does)

I have access the the web server code but not sure what to change.

**EDIT**
Used [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512%28VS.85%29.aspx) and got the same result: the cgi application no longer executes from the browser but is interpreted as a file for download. (i.e. - Save this file?)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, you're saying that when you add that `putenv` call to your CGI program, the Web server no longer executes that CGI program. And when you remove that line and recompile, the Web server *will* run your program. Have I understood you correctly? Have you tried with any other environment variables? Or other values for COMSPEC?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Setting a random string as the value for COMSPEC the cgi DID run. I also set the env var SERVER_ADMIN=t@aol.com as a test - no problems. In both of these tests, it did run correctly. Only when I specify the entire path to cmd.exe it will NOT run.

Comment: What's the name of your CGI program (especially the extension)?

Comment: Are you running the CGI in Apache or IIS; or are you running a custom webserver that you have the code for (the question makes it sound lke the later, but I'm not sure)?

Comment: @Michael Burr- This is the GoAhed embedded web server http://www.goahead.com/products/webserver/download.aspx  It seems the problem is when calling cmd.exe the cgi will not run...

Comment: To be clear - you're setting COMSPEC in the web server, then invoking the CGI application from a web browser?
What is COMSPEC before you set it? On my system, it is `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`, which resolves to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`.

Comment: When the CGI doesn't run, and you're prompted to Save the file, try saving the file. Is the file that is saved the cgi executable (byte for byte) or something else?

Comment: @Jason: I'm setting COMSPEC in the cgi executable. However, I set it in the web server and I got the same result. How do I check if it saved byte for byte?

Comment: CreateProcess() does not work either =(